# toggle Button Show/Hide Div keeps jumping to upwards

Tags: jquery, html, css

Good Day

I have 3 toggle buttons, that shows/hide 3 divs:

ISSUE: Whenever I click any of the buttons, the page scrolls up, but not to the top...It is very annoying since it directs the users focus away from the toggled content...

I don't think it is the href="#" since I did specify bookmarks for them...

Note that the last two divs has the same amount of content, but the first one has a bit less...

Why is the viewport shifting upward everytime I click the buttons?
What is the best way to fix it?

```
         <div id="featuredToggle">
              <ul>
                  <li><a class="latestClick clickedStyle" href="#latestInner">Latest</a></li>
                  <li><a class="make" href="#make">Make</a></li>
                  <li><a class="models" href="#models">Models</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>

         <div id="latestInner"> 
           content here
         </div>
         <div id="make">
           content
         </div>
         <div id="models">
           content
         </div>
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#make').hide(50);
            $('#models').hide(50);

            $('#featuredToggle ul li a').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                if ($(this).hasClass('latestClick')) {

                    $('#featuredToggle ul li a.make').removeClass('clickedStyle');
                    $('#featuredToggle ul li a.models').removeClass('clickedStyle');
                    $(this).addClass('clickedStyle');

                    $('#make').hide(200);
                    $('#models').hide(200);
                    $('#latestInner').show(500);

                } else if ($(this).hasClass('make')) {

                    $('#featuredToggle ul li a.latestClick').removeClass('clickedStyle');
                    $('#featuredToggle ul li a.models').removeClass('clickedStyle');
                    $(this).addClass('clickedStyle');

                    $('#latestInner').hide(200);
                    $('#models').hide(200);
                    $('#make').show(500);

                } else if ($(this).hasClass('models')) {

                    $('#featuredToggle ul li a.latestClick').removeClass('clickedStyle');
                    $('#featuredToggle ul li a.make').removeClass('clickedStyle');
                    $(this).addClass('clickedStyle');

                    $('#latestInner').hide(200);
                    $('#make').hide(200);
                    $('#models').show(500);
                }
            });

        });
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could it possible be because the page size is being reduced as of the loss of these elements. Try setting the CSS of the body and html to something like: `min-hieght:100%;height:100%;max-height:100%;`. See what happens.

Comment: I though so, but I though maybe there is a solution/trick that I do not know about...I will try and see what happens

Comment: could do `.css({'opacity':'0'})` that way the element technically still exists and won't change the body's height etc. Only as a test. Not a solution.

Comment: I am guessing it's the lack of content in the divs that's making the page scroll, it's hard to debug this without a fiddle

Comment: also with click functions I've found returning false at the end of the function; with some browsers like firefox and opera specially. Prevents any the click event. Whereas preventDeault() only works with ie and safari  believe.

Comment: Thanks Beneto. how do I return false? code please

Comment: @Beneto `e.preventDefault` works in all major browsers. It is implemented by jQuery to be cross-browser compatible. `return false;` is simply equivalent to `e.stopPropagation();e.preventDefault();`, which is only necessary if the element you click is not the link itself, but is inside of it.

Comment: sorry I got mixed up with `event.preventDefault();`. Just like a normal return function. At the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mistype `#model` as `#models` multiple times in your code, which probably causes the issue with toggling. Your `div`'s id is `model`. The link wouldn't correctly refer to any element. Also, most of your code is completely redundant. Always reuse similar code. You never want to be redoing the same thing for each element. Consider the following simplification:

```
$(function() {
    $('#make').hide(50);
    $('#model').hide(50);

    $('#featuredToggle ul li a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#featuredToggle ul li a').not(this).removeClass('clickedStyle');
        $(this).addClass('clickedStyle');

        $('#featuredToggle ul li a').not(this).each(function() {
            $($(this).attr('href')).hide(200);
        });

        $($(this).attr('href')).show(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: I actually mistyped it here, it is actually "models" in my code, otherwise it would not have worked...Issue is with the viewport jumping upwards, I think it is because of the fact that space is being removed from the viewport when any div is hidden...thank you very much for the code review...appreciate.

Comment: @DextrousDave Oh your links are becoming absolute links before the code fires, you can use jQuery to get the actual attr instead. (updated) - http://jsfiddle.net/25HFp/

Comment: Cool, thank you. Works great...But does not really answer my problem on the issue of the viewport adjustng size when hiding showing the divs

Comment: @DextrousDave Can you reproduce the error on http://jsfiddle.net? You can edit the one I posted above

Comment: Hi nbrooks...See my fiddle you requested: http://jsfiddle.net/sKje2/  If you look at the scroolbar on the right hand side, you see it jumping up and down when toggling. It is abviously because of the fact that height is being deducted from the viewport the the split second when a div is hidden and displayed again...I guess I should just add a DYNAMIC min-height on the parent div...

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it is because you hide them faster than you show them so for a slight second the overal page height is shorter than it should.